# vertical align image in div

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

Okay here is the problem, I have images of different sizes, but that doesn't really matter because their width is always greater then their height, and all images are resized to a 100px width (height still is different in each image)

I am trying to vertical align the images inside a div of 100px x 100px. I tried all kinds of things. line-height, margin's auto, table cell methods all don't work for me...

Here's the html:

```
<div class="kassabon_product_image">
<img src="product1.png" />
</div>
```

and here's the CSS

```
.kassabon_product_image{
float: left;
display:table-cell;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
border: 1px solid #D5D0C6;
line-height: 100px;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.kassabon_product_image img{
width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This question was asked here on [so] at least 10 times that I can remember. There are probably hundreds of this exact question here. Please search before posting.

Comment: I searched for it on google and Stack Overflow for atleast 1.5 hours, none of the answers given would help me.

I tried setting margins top and bottom on auto, playing with the display:table-cell; method, even saw something with position:relative; top:50%; (but that just put the image-top at half of the div). I'm posting this because the answers that are posted don't work in this case, for some weird reason.

Comment: Here on [so], it's expected that you explain what you've tried, and how that didn't work for you. It'll show your effort, plus it would give us the correct direction to help you. Also, the very solution that you accepted as correct, I remember answering exactly that at least 2 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.kassabon_product_image{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Remove the vertical-align from the img and that should do the trick.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work. Like I said in the question, vertical-align in the parent div doesn't work.

Comment: Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vLYpz/ I created and work your way up from there. It should work just fine.

Comment: Well... that was stupid of me. using a float in combination with vertical align just disables the align. Deleted the float and now it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Floating elements cancels the display property (essentially sets it to display:block). You can wrap the parent with another div that is floated, or depending on your design set the element next to this one to display:table-cell as well (yields similar results as two floated elements) Really depends on what you are trying to accomplish though.

Comment: Hmm, haven't thought of the display:table-cell. Thanks

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly yes it does. It works for me just fine in IE 8-10.

Answer (score 1):

see comments

```
.kassabon_product_image{
float: left;
text-align: center; /*using text-align:center in the outer div will center all elements inside the div*/
display:inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
border: 1px solid #D5D0C6;
line-height: 100px;
}

.kassabon_product_image img{
width: 100px;
/*vertical-align:middle;*/ /*this is the wrong place to align*/
}
```

Comment: text-align does only horizontal alignment as far as I know. But tested it either way, but no, doesn't work.